# Using Javascript FileReader with huge files

Tags: javascript, onload, filereader

I have a problem using the Javascript FileRead trying to read huge files.

For example, I have a text file of 200mb and everytime I read this file the code stops working.

Its possible to read the text file, but for example ONLY the first 10 lines or stop reading after 10mb?

This is my code:

```
var file = form.getEl().down('input[type=file]').dom.files[0];
var reader = new FileReader();

reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
                return function(e) {
                    data = e.target.result;
                    form.displayedData=data;
                };
            })(file);

reader.readAsText(file);
```

The `e.target.result` always has the whole data of the file.

What can I do here?

Thx

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This will only read the first 10 mb:

```
var file = form.getEl().down('input[type=file]').dom.files[0];
var reader = new FileReader();

reader.onload = function(e) {
    var data = e.target.result;
    form.displayedData = data;
};

reader.readAsText(file.slice(0, 10 * 1024 * 1024));
```

Comment: Yes this read first 10mb but file is still in memory, i think the original question was about reading huge files and not loading whole file into memory. Am I not right?

Comment: Yes @Yetti my problem is same. if we try open 4GB file, file.slice will try load entire file.

Comment: @Yetti no it only loads 10mb into memory.

Comment: @Fatih `Blob.slice` (same as `File.slice`) _shouldn't_ load the entire file into memory, it's basically true file streaming if you only read by slices (that said though, the actual underlying behavior is browser and system specific, e.g. it's possible that a 200MB file will be loaded into memory on a 64GB RAM system, but not a 20GB file). Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24833487/what-is-html5-file-slice-method-actually-doing and https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/storage/browser/blob/README.md

Comment: Thanks @JohnWeisz I'll try.