# File slicing in JavaScript results in empty blob

Tags: javascript, html, chunking

I am implementing a browser-based chunked file uploader. To open the file I am using `<input type="file" id="fileSelector" />` and this piece of code (simplified):

```
$('#fileSelector').on('change', function () {
    _file = evt.target.files[0];
});
```

I am slicing the file into chunks, but not reading the chunk into memory (not explicitly).

**Problem**: occasionally (for less than 0.1% of uploaded files) the chunk sliced from the underlying file is empty. E.g. during uploading a large file things go well, and then in the middle of that file calling:

```
var _blob = _file.slice(chunk.start, chunk.end, _file.type);
```

results in an empty slice (`_blob.size` is 0). Sending such blob to the server (.NET 4.6) results in `Request.InputStream` being empty. I am sending bniary data:

```
_xhr.setRequestHeader('content-type', 'application/octet-stream');
_xhr.send(_blob);
```

I should also mention that calling `_file.slice` again produces same empty blob. I can observe this in Chrome 57, Chrome 60 (Win and Mac), Mac Safari 10.1.1 and in Edge 15. Other browsers are also possible.

What can be wrong? Things I am considering:

- file is in use
- file/disk is corrupt
- the blob is GCed by JavaScript engine in the meantime - if that can be the case how to make sure it is not GCed?
- browser bug (I found this, but not sure if it is related: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=167111)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24834417/1606432 This gives some further insight into the File & Blob check

Comment: Could you share how you calculate chunk start and end. Have you tried with Firefox/Edge?

Comment: @K3N Yes, tried in lots of browsers and OSes and this works 99,9% of the time. Start and end are calculated more less like this: var start = N * _chunkSize; var end = Math.min(start + _chunkSize, _file.size); Where N is the current chunk number (0-based).

Comment: Why and how do you use a FileReader ?

Comment: @Kaiido - good point. We actually don't. I have updated the question now.

Comment: @K3N I am using a customized version of plupload3. Here is chunk count calculation: https://github.com/andy250/plupload/blob/3.x/src/FileUploader.js#L84. The complete process is spread over more files in addition to FileUploader.js: https://github.com/andy250/plupload/blob/3.x/src/core/Queue.js and probably couple more. I seriously doubt these calculations are the problem though since the process usually works. I could agree that there is some variable scoping issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer turned out to be very simple: that's what happens when the file being uploaded is gone (renamed, deleted).

Comment: While this issue helped me somehow, the real solver for me was https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32898082/splitting-a-file-into-chunks-with-javascript, anyway +1

Answer (score -1):

```
var offset = currentChunk * chunkSize;
        var currentFilePart = rr.files.item(0).slice(offset, (offset+chunkSize));
        var cFilePart = new FileReader();
        //var ar1 = new Uint8Array(currentFilePart.arrayBuffer());
         
        var Rajar2 = new Uint8Array(chunkSize);
        var DSA = new Uint8Array(1000);
        var DATop = 0;
        var arrTop = 0;

        var data = currentFilePart.result;
        var ar1 = new Uint8Array(data);
        alert(ar1[0]);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).