# blob.slice() results in an empty blob - javascript

Tags: javascript, file-upload

I am trying to send a large file to a server, so I am using the chunking technique in order to do it in a robust way.

```
    private readonly sendChunk = (file: File, progressModel: ProgressResponseModel): void => {
        const offset = progressModel.Offset;
        if (offset > file.size)
            throw new Error("Offset cannot be greater than the file size");

        const expectedSize = progressModel.ExpectedChunkSize;

        const blobChunk = file.slice(offset, expectedSize);

        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onload = (ev: Event): void => {
             if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status === 200) {
                    const progress = this.progressFromText(xhr.responseText);

                    if (progress.Offset >= 0) {
                        this.sendChunk(file, progress);
                    }

                    console.log(`${progress.Progress} %`);
                }
            }

        xhr.open("POST", this._uploadChunkUrl, true);
        xhr.send(blobChunk);
    }
```

The server sends back where to start the new chunk from and how big it should be. The above function is executed in a recursive manner as you can see.

However, if the file requires more than 1 chunk to be sent, the second time I call `const blobChunk = file.slice(offset, expectedSize);` I get an empty chunk (length 0).

I can guarantee that the `file` arg is always valid (when `console.log`ed).

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46055733/file-slicing-in-javascript-results-in-empty-blob), but I am sure my file is not removed or renamed.
I've also seen [this issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=167111). I get the same behavior for both Chrome and Firefox (latest versions), also Edge.

Thanks!

**UPDATE**
Okay, so I did a dummy method in order to isolate this issue:

```
    readonly chunkIt = (file: Blob): void => {
        var offset = 0;
        var length = 512 * 1024;

        while (offset >= 0) {
            const blobChunk = file.slice(offset, length);
            console.log(blobChunk);

            offset += length;
            if (offset > file.size) offset = -1;
        }
    }
```

And using it:

```
   $("input[name='fileUpload']").on("change", (e) => {
        const files = e.target.files;
        if (typeof files === "undefined" || files === null || files.length === 0)
            e.preventDefault();

        const file = files[0];

        this._client.chunkIt(file);
    });
```

Logs a correct `Blob` only the first time, the following are all empty.

**SOLVED**

From this issue - [Splitting a File into Chunks with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32898082/splitting-a-file-into-chunks-with-javascript) it turned out that I've forgot to offset my `end` index.

Comment: use `file.splice`

Comment: I am using typescript and there is no such definition in the `Blob` interface, only `slice()`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `splice()` instead of `slice()`

**Replace**

```
const blobChunk = file.slice(offset, expectedSize);
```

**with**

```
const blobChunk = file.splice(offset, expectedSize);
```

Comment: `file.splice is not a function`